# Enforcing code standards in git before commit is accepted

Tags: git, unit-testing, pre-commit-hook

Alright, here's the scenario: A team of developers wants to ensure all new code matches the defined coding standards and all the unit tests are passing before a commit is accepted. Here's the trick, all of the tests need to run on a dedicated testing machine and we do not have access to modify the git server so this must be done using a local commit hook on each dev machine.

While the specs are pretty strict (we're not switching to windows or subversion, for example) this is a real world problem so there is some flexibility if you have a solution that almost fits.

- We're using Git and *nix.
- The updated code needs to be sent to another server to run the test suite.
- A list of modified files needs to be provided to ensure they match the coding standard.
- Its a rather large codebase, so we should send the smallest amount of information necessary to ensure identical copies of the codebase.
- If the tests fail a message needs to be displayed with the error and the commit should be blocked.
- Assume we trust our dev team and its okay to allow the tests to be bypassed with `--no-verify` option.

**The question:** What is the best way to get the test server to sync up with the local environment to run the tests? Some sort of hash-to-hash matching with a git patch for the new commit? Skip Git altogether and just do an rsync? Something else altogether?

**Update 8/7/13:** I shot myself in the foot by even mentioning the remote repo. The point isn't to block the code from being pushed to the shared / remote repo, its to prevent the local commit from even happening. Whether or not this would be considered a best practice is not really the point in this case, as this is specific to a small team of developers who all want this exact functionality. The question is about the best way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Isn't this basically what pull requests are for? (Granted, you may not be using GitHub on this project but you can almost certainly do something similar.)

Comment: Pull requests are for reviewing code, yes, but the idea here is that code should not even be committed to the repo unless it passes a first, automated review.

Comment: Many Github projects also use a continuous integration server like Travis to run tests on the code in pull requests and report the results - so it's not just for code reviews. Also, code in pull requests isn't technically in the repo until the pull request gets merged. That's why it's called a [`pull`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) request.

Comment: "we do not have access to modify the git server so this must be done using a local commit hook on each dev machine."

Or you could set up an intermediate server that pushes to the main repo after verifying the commit.

Comment: I see what you're saying about the pull request, but this is less about locking down the repo and more about giving devs that immediate feedback as part of their normal workflow without having to go to an external tool like Travis / Jenkins or waiting for an email to show up.

I like the idea of an intermediate repo. That hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: "Assume we trust our dev team..." Do you trust them or do you need to check their every commit for style violations? Seems like you're looking for a technical solution to a social problem (that may not even exist).

Comment: This is not an arbitrary set of rules being imposed on a group of developers. This is a small team of devs who decided together that this would be an incredibly helpful tool to them all on a particular project.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to know what sorts of tests.  You talk about getting 'immediate feedback', but copying files to a remote server and running an unknown set of tests is going to take time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a custom git command which:

1. Temporarily does the commit
2. Pushes it to the remote server
3. Runs the tests (using a CI server, `post-receive` hook, or `ssh`)
4. Reverts the commit if the tests fail

Create an executable called `git-test-n-commit` and place it in your path:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Committing results..."
git commit "$@"
echo "Pushing to remote testing server..."
git push remote-server-git-url remote-branch -f
echo "Running tests"
ssh remote-server 'cd my_repo; run-my-tests' || 
   (echo "Tests failed, undoing commit" && git reset HEAD^)
```

Then instead of calling `git commit ARGS`, the developers can call `git test-n-commit ARGS`.  If the tests pass the code will remain committed.  If the tests fail it will be as if it was never committed.

Answer (score 12):

Local commit hooks are definitely not what you want here.

Your requirement that 'we do not have access to modify the git server so this must be done using a local commit hook on each dev machine' is completely bogus.  You can always set up another repository that is your 'test remote' which you have full control over (which will then sync up with the git server you have no control over).

Once you set up this test remote, you can add hooks to run your tests on any push.  The effort to type `git push test-remote my-branch` to get test results is pretty minimal.

[Continuous integration with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249526/continuous-integration-with-git)

Also check out Jenkins, gitlab, etc...

---

Update after 8/7/13:

So you really want to do some 'tests' on a remote server to prevent commits.  If you want to prevent based on the content of the commit itself, use the `pre-commit` hook. [See this question for how to get a list of changed files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412450/git-pre-commit-hook-changed-added-files)  Once you have those changed files, you can get them to a remote server using `scp` or `rsync` and run a test command with `ssh`.

If you need to check the commit message use the `commit-msg` hook.

Here is a good tutorial on hooks: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

It also mentions a few reasons why it might be a bad idea.

> They’re often used to enforce certain policies, although it’s important to note that these scripts aren’t transferred during a clone. You can enforce policy on the server side to reject pushes of commits that don’t conform to some policy, but it’s entirely up to the developer to use these scripts on the client side. So, these are scripts to help developers, and they must be set up and maintained by them, although they can be overridden or modified by them at any time.

Answer (score 12):

Short answer:

## DON'T

---

Long answer:

Not being able to do a commit because of some strange local hooks seems odd to me: you have to separate making a commit (i.e. saving your changes) from publishing this commit.

While it's perfecly reasonable to have a `pre-receive` hook on the git server you mention that enforces your rules, it would be dramatic for the repos of your devs: every time they want to save their work, try out something new or whatever, they would first have to polish their code before they could do the commit.

This would be counterproductive: people would feel like back in the bad old days when they had to commit anything to *the* repo and everybody could see their errors, bad coding style and so on. You would lose the freedom that a DVCS gives you: cheap branching, local history while maintaining a central repo for the production code.

**Do not enforce anything** when doing a local commit.

Comment: What you're saying is absolutely right in almost every case. However, this is a small team working on a private project with high standards and as a group they have decided this is the route they want to take. The question is not about best practices but about the best method to achieve a goal for a specific team.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach I've seen is git+gerrit+jenkins. The gerrit introduces a notion of a changeset. The jenkins gerrit plugin could build each published changeset (running any kind of tests you would like) and mark them as "verified", then verified changeset could be merged into a master branch. If changeset fails build, committer receives a notification email, then he could amend the commit and update the changeset.

Answer (score 1):

After setting up an intermediate server as others have suggested, set your `pre-receive` hook up to run a script over the incoming commit and normalise it to your coding standards. Often coding standards are defined by computer-enforcable rules. Don't make your developers go around tweaking whitespace hither and tither when a simple bash script or whatever could do it for them. And if you have a script to do that, why make the developer run it manually when it can be ran automatically on each `push` to your intermediate repo.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Makefile that:

1. Copies current files to test server.
2. Finds the output of the unit tests.

2.1. If there are no anomalies, run 'git commit'

2.2 If there are anomalies, echo an error.

Using Makefiles to do my compiling AND commits has been a godsend. I can automate complex formatting and file cleanup before committing.

Edit:

Of course, Makefiles are not the only things you can do. Ant/Bash/other scripting languages can do this for you.